# CSV.parse work fine under development in rails but does not work under production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

1.Parse csv file like below in rails:

```
  require 'csv'
  require 'cmess/guess_encoding'
  require 'iconv'

def parse_csv (file_name)
    charset = guess_encoding file_name
    csv=nil
    File.open(file_name, "rb", :external_encoding => charset, :internal_encoding => "UTF-8") { |f| csv = f.read }
    Rails.logger.error("File read csv:#{csv}")
    csv=Iconv.conv("utf-8", charset, csv) unless charset == "UTF-8"
    Rails.logger.error("Iconv conv csv:#{csv}")
    rows = CSV.parse(csv, :col_sep => ",")
    Rails.logger.error("CSV parse csv:#{rows}")
    rows
end
```

2.Config/application.eb config：

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'csv'
require 'rails/all'
```

3.Under Development it will print all 3 logs and works correctly but it only prints the first 2 logs under production,it seems that CSV.parse here does not work like under development,it's really tough for me to find the reason,does somebody know what's going on here??

Comment: so what actually happens in production? do you get an error? does an exception get raised?

Comment: I checked in production log for details info,and find that it said Java::JavaLang::ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (-69);and plus print the string that generated from File.open,find that it has an extra question sign af the first,like below:"?Purchaser,Purchaser ID,Supplier,Supplier ID,Product,Product ID,Billing Rate
Le Meridien Shimei Bay Beach Resort and Spa,5033,hainan company,12897,Lamp T5-21W 2700K,665369,0.5",btw,file has 7 columns in total,string encoding is UTF-8 so it will skip Iconv.conv to CSV.parse,here it says the above error,i think may be question sign that results in this issue

Comment: Do you know why the string will generate a question sign at the first?I feel a litte confused here for File.open function.Besides,i split the string manually that generated by File.open then it will work correct and does not cause the above error.

Comment: Your CSV has some invalid UTF-8 data in it - being interpreted as the question mark.

Comment: For ensuring CSV's encoding is UTF-8,i open it using NotePad++ and convert it to UTF-8, then import this file,but still has this problem,so strange

Comment: It will add a hexadecimal string:'\xEF\xBB\xBF' behind first header column string, so it will parse error,here we just need to replace that string with empty then it will work correct!!!!!